# Using Knockout.Js to bind array to a table and an item of the array to another element

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have an observable array that holds a list of people and a table that displays their first name, with a select button for each. When the user clicks the select button I'd like another element on screen to display the person's full name. Is there a way to get it so that if a person is removed from the array, it also removes the element displaying their full name?

[jsFiddle example here](http://jsfiddle.net/jCkuY/3/)

Edit: I can achieve this by putting `self.SelectedPerson(false);` in the remove function, but is there a better way of doing it?

2nd Edit: Changed the jsFiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One useful thing here is that in the click method in a `foreach` loop you get the current data item sent to the function, which means that you can set the `SelectedAccount` observable to the item sent to the function.

Check this updated jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jCkuY/1/

And for the remove function you can either set the selectedAccount to an empty `Account` object or even to null, but then you'll need to use an if binding perhaps.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've changed my example (forgot to hit update!). It feels this way that changing the Selected observable to null/empty/false is surplus. Is there a better way to have this so that the call to remove it from the array will also automatically change that observable based on the element that has been removed??